# Is it possible to install Photomatix under wine?

Tags: linux, .net-framework, wine, hdr

Is it possible to install [Photomatix](http://www.hdrsoft.com/) under wine?  I'm running Ubuntu 9.04, and I've tried both the default download and the embedded .net version.  The first attempts to install the .net framework 1.1, and fails, while the 2nd appears to install but won't run.

After a bit of googling, er, binging, I tried adding the .net 2.0 runtime via winetricks, and now it appears to install OK, but still won't run - either from the wine menu, or from the command line.

Is it possible?  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Installl Wine from the [WineHQ APT repository.](http://www.winehq.org/site/download-deb)

Get winetricks, start them and tick the box to install the corefonts and dotnet 2.0.

```
$ wget http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
$ chmod u+x winetricks
$ ./winetricks
```

Download Photomatix for Windows and run the setup application.

```
$ wine PhotomatixPro303.exe
```

The icon for Photomatix is in the Wine -> Programs menu.

( this might be help you )

From This Blog :http://panospace.wordpress.com/2008/07/14/photomatix-30-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Those are all the steps I tried, but no luck - it won't run.